# Cart Throb: The totals of the cart item amounts do not match order amounts. 10413

Tags: cartthrob

Having a serious issue with Cart Throb:

When checking out I am getting this error

```
Your payment failed: Failed: The totals of the cart item amounts do not match order amounts. 10413 Try checking out again »
```

I am using Paypal Express

Cart Throb version 2.2.2
EE version 2.5.2

I checked my plugin and this line is already there:

```
if (!empty($_POST['PR']) || !empty($_POST['price']) || $this->order('pp_alt_total'))
```

What could be causing this error?  Please help this is a live store.

Here is my checkout code:

```
{if "{exp:cartthrob:total_items_count}" > 0}

   <div id="checkout_totals">
    <table>
     <tr>
      <td><span class="sale_price">Total</span></td>
      <td><span class="sale_price"><span class="cart_total">{exp:cartthrob:cart_total}</span></span></td>
     </tr>       
     <tr>
      <td>Subtotal</td>
      <td><span class="cart_subtotal">{exp:cartthrob:cart_subtotal}</span></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Shipping</td>
      <td><span class="cart_shipping">{exp:cartthrob:cart_shipping}</span></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Tax</td>
      <td><span class="cart_tax">{exp:cartthrob:cart_tax}</span></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Discount</td>
      <td>-<span class="cart_discount">{exp:cartthrob:cart_discount}</span></td>
     </tr>
    </table>
    </div>
   <div id="checkout_notes">
 *All fields are required</p>
   </div>




  {!-- add secure_action="yes" parameter if you want to submit this form using HTTPS:// connection --}
  {exp:cartthrob:checkout_form 
   return="shop/order_info"}

   {!-- {if {exp:cartthrob:view_setting allow_gateway_selection="yes"}}
    <p><label for="gateway">Select a payment method</label>
    {exp:cartthrob:gateway_select id="gateway"}</p>
   {/if}--}
   Coupon: &lt;input type="text" name="coupon_code" /&gt; 
   <div id="checkout_form_gateway_fields">
   {gateway_fields}
   </div>

      &lt;input type="submit" class="cart_submit_button" value="Complete Checkout" /&gt;
  {/exp:cartthrob:checkout_form}


  {if:else}
   <p>You have no items in your cart. <a href="{path=shop/index}">Continue shopping</a></p>
  {/if}
```

Comment: For the record, for code just indent 4 spaces (or click {} button in the editor), `[code]` doesn't work on Stack Exchange.

Comment: I'm not sure about CartThrob specifically, but this error is why we haven't implemented line-item details for Paypal in Store yet. Is there a way to disable CT from sending line-item details to Paypal?

Comment: Peter - I'd suggest posting this to the CartThrob support forums, where you're sure to get help.

Comment: Derek,I wish you were right.  I have posted there with no feedback at all, tweeted them with no feedback at all.  I have had another post in the CT forums for over a month with no response.

Comment: Peter, were you able to get this issue resolved? If yes, can you post your fix here as an answer?

Comment: nope could not find a solution to this. What I did was remove the CPC shipping plugin to get it working again. I guess is there is a bug in the plugin. I have not been able to get any support from Cart Throb for this or any other support questions for a month and a half now.

Comment: I just found out this issue was not fixed.  Has anyone else ever came across this error?

Comment: Yeah I'm having the exact same problem at the moment... same error and can't get to the bottom of it..